# How to import fl package in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to import `fl.core.*` but I can't find it.

There are only `flash.something` to import.

What should I do? Do i have to set something in project properties?

Thank you.

Comment: What software are you using? Usually it is within the install folder as Pan already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the fl classes in the the flash cs install fold.In my experience, we use the classed as a library in the project. You can copy the class to you project or make a library project with the fl classes and use this library in other project.

Here is some information about fl class（where you can find the classes)

[fl classes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fd3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys. I clearly get it now. I just start with only Flash Developer. However, if you

want to use `fl` class, you have to start with another program which is Adobe Flash CS5 ( or

5.5 ). I find some `fla` file and import it into adobe flash CS5, then export it to `swc`.

So you can copy swc file into your Flash Developer and right click to Add into your project.

Then you can use fl class. I dont know I'm doing it right or wrong but it works.